# How to extract a digit from an image with numbered grid opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, mnist

I am trying to analyse an image and extract each number to then process using a CNN trained with MNIST. The images show garments with a grid-like pattern in each intersection of the grid there is a number (e.g. 0412). I want to analyse and detect which number it is to then store it's coordinates. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to preprocess the image given that it is quite noisy and with multiple numbers. I have tried using contours and it didn't work. I also put the image into binary and there are areas of the image which are unreadable. My initial idea was to isolate each number to then process.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow. Incase you haven't read it, please consider to provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is usually helpful for the answerer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).